# How to play one music at a time on Activity launch

Tags: android, media-player

Whenever i click on music, i want to launch an Activity that play the selected song, however i can't seems to get this right. I have tried many codes, but all to no avail.

Here is the button that will launch the activity

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicPlaying.class);
                    i.putExtra("song", position);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

And below is the Activity that receive intent from the above button.

```
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.music_playing);
            value = getIntent().getIntExtra("song", 0);
    ...
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            } else {
                playMusic();
            }
    ...
}
```

Edit: The app plays two songs at a time instead of playing only selected song.

Comment: What type of error did you get? How your media file encoded and where did you put it?

Comment: The app plays two songs at a time instead of playing only selected song.

Comment: Show code where you initialise MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be very careful with MediaPlayer state transactions, check [diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram).

For example when you call stop(), you cannot call start() again until you prepare the MediaPlayer again.

In your case it looks like you didn't release MediaPlayer when the host Activity destroyed (ex. screen rotation), can be done like that

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mp != null)
        mp.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. Anyways, i have found a solution to it, and thanks for your response.